# "Layer X : Feature Y for attribute update not found." for every single feature in QGIS with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm using PyQGIS on QGIS 3.28 Firenze.

I'm trying to update a field with a custom script however for some reasons I keep getting this error "Layer customer_enhanced: Feature Y for attribute update not found." for every feature Y.

Here is my code :

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import *

layer_name = "customer_enhanced"

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

old_field_idx = layer.fields().lookupField('monthly_household_income')
clean_field_idx = layer.fields().lookupField('monthly_household_income_cleaned')

provider = layer.dataProvider()

#checks whether the clean field already exists and if not creates it
if(clean_field_idx == -1):
    clean_field = QgsField('monthly_household_income_cleaned', QVariant.Double)
    provider.addAttributes([clean_field])
    layer.updateFields()
    clean_field_idx = layer.fields().lookupField('monthly_household_income_cleaned')

# Loop through each feature in the layer and update the 'monthly_household_income_cleaned' field
for feature in provider.getFeatures():
    if(feature.id() < 20):
        value = feature.attribute(old_field_idx)
        
        # Clean the value
        if value != '':
            value = str(value)
            value = value.replace(' ', '')
            value = value.replace('>', '')
            value = value.replace('.', '')
            value = value.replace('a_charge', '')
            value = value.replace('Ar', '')
            value = value.replace('NULL', '')

            # If the value contains a range, calculate the average
            if '-' in value:
                value = str(round((int(value.split('-')[0]) + int(value.split('-')[1])) / 2))
            
            value = None if value == '' else float(value)
            
            print(provider.changeAttributeValues({feature.id(): {clean_field_idx: value}}))

#provider.deleteAttributes([old_field_idx])
#layer.updateFields()

#provider.renameAttributes({clean_field_idx: 'monthly_household_income'})
#layer.updateFields()
```

A few notes :

- my layer has over 10'000 rows but for debugging sake I'm only trying on the first 20 for now
- for now the idea is simply to create a new field with the cleaned value. I could also try modifying directly the initial field, which is what I'm going to try while waiting for an answer
- this line `print(provider.changeAttributeValues({feature.id(): {clean_field_idx: value}}))` returns `True` everytime which should indicate success as per [the documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsVectorDataProvider.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorDataProvider.changeAttributeValues)
- the console doesn't return any error, the message "Layer customer_enhanced: Feature Y for attribute update not found." appears in QGIS as a red banner, hence I suppose the problem comes from QGIS and not from my coding?
- I tried adding `startEditing()` and `commtChanges()` even though it shouldn't be required as I use a dataprovider, got the same issue anyway

Here is my guess : I think it's not very clear what a feature ID refers to. Is it an internal, hidden ID ? Is it the row number of the feature when the layer is initially added ? Is it the number in the "id" field of my attribute table ? These are my leads more than actual questions.

When I get print `feature.id()` I get 1, ... , 14235 which is the number of features my layer has, though this does not correspond to what is in the 'id' field (they are unique though not ranging from 1 to len(rows))

I will try other methods in the meanwhile but for now I would rather understand why it doesn't work like this.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Whenever I tried to change an attribute all new features got deleted. The problem occurred because a user did load the .shp file a second time into the project. After removing the second instance of the same file from the project my script went fine.

Here my script and my new error check

Script:

```
idxPlotZusatz = zusatz_lyr.fields().indexFromName('plot')
for f in zusatz_lyr.getFeatures():
    zusatz_lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({f.id(): {idxPlotZusatz: 1}})
```

Errorcheck:

```
def check_layer_duplicates(self):
    """
    Checkt, ob eine .shp file mehrfach im Projekt liegt

    rtype: bool
    """

    project = QgsProject.instance()
    alle_layer = project.mapLayers().values()

    shapefile_counts = {}

    # alle Layer checken
    for layer in alle_layer:
        if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer):
            quelle = layer.source()
            if quelle.endswith('.shp'):
                if quelle in shapefile_counts:
                    shapefile_counts[quelle] += 1
                else:
                    shapefile_counts[quelle] = 1

    # Liste aller doppelten layer
    duplicate_sources = [source for source, count in shapefile_counts.items() if count > 1]

    # Ergebnis
    if len(duplicate_sources) > 0:
        question_msg = QMessageBox()
        question_msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        question_msg.setWindowTitle('Layer mehrfach ins Projekt geladen!')
        question_msg.setText(f"Die Datei(en) wurden mehrfach ins Projekt geladen:\n\n"
                             f"{','.join(duplicate_sources)} \n\n"
                             f"Das kann dazu führen, dass die Layerinhalte gelöscht werden.\n"
                             f"Wenn möglich die Duplikate entfernen.\n\n"
                             f"Soll das Tool trotzdem ausgeführt werden?")

        question_msg.addButton("Fortsetzen", 8)
        question_msg.addButton("Abbrechen", 8)

        # Msg anzeigen
        result = question_msg.exec_()
        if result == 1: # 1 == abbrechen
            return False

    return True
```